# Save data to new database on MongoDB Atlas within a cluster

Tags: mongodb, connection-string, mongodb-atlas

I created a new database inside my MongoDB Atlas Cluster called "production", so far my server has been writing all the data to the "test" database in the cluster.

How do I get the connection-string for the new production database so I can write to it and instead of "test" database in my cluster?

Thank you!

// Currently writing to "test" but want to write to "production"
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your connection string you have the database name, replace test to production and it will work.

Let me know if there is an issue.

Comment: My connection doesn't have the database name? it says "MONGODB_URL=mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@cluster0.05ftg9.mongodb.net/?authSource=admin{etc...}"

Comment: Generally this is the format for the connection string 

mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

if its not there the you can add it manually. for reference: https://mongoing.com/docs/reference/connection-string.html

Answer (score 0):

faced the same problem, just add your database's name following your connection string
for example,

'databasestring/production'